# Need to combine two row values into a single field in one row SQL reports

Tags: sql

I am doing SSRS reports with SQL.  I am doing reports that return IP addresses and many systems will have two rows or more rows of IP addresses.  These values are pulled from multiple tables.  All these are in SCCM Configuration Manager.  I am looking to find what syntax I need to research to make this work.

current report

Select computer, IP from Table

| computer | IP |
| --- | --- |
| server1 | 10.0.0.1 |
| server1 | 10.0.0.2 |
| server1 | 10.0.0.3 |
| server2 | 10.0.0.4 |
| server2 | 10.0.0.5 |

Desired

| computer | IP |
| --- | --- |
| server1 | 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3 |
| server2 | 10.0.0.4, 10.0.0.5 |

Comment: tag your database and mention its version, since you mentioned ssrs , im guessing you are using sql server , if yes what's its version?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(COMPUTER_NAME,IP) AS
(
  SELECT 'server1',        '10.0.0.1' UNION ALL
  SELECT'server1',        '10.0.0.2' UNION ALL
  SELECT'server1',        '10.0.0.3' UNION ALL
  SELECT'server2',        '10.0.0.4' UNION ALL
  SELECT'server2' ,       '10.0.0.5' 
)
SELECT C.COMPUTER_NAME,STRING_AGG(C.IP,',')AGG_IP
FROM CTE AS C
GROUP BY C.COMPUTER_NAME
```

Starting SQL Server 2017 you can use STRING_AGG()-function